# Service-Based Database not saving after I close form

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

I'm making a Windows form in Visual Studio 2019.

I have a datagridview filled with data, and I need to import it to a table in a .mdf database that I created.

I tried this code:

```
string ConnString = (@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|pieces.mdf" + ";Integrated Security=True");
string StrQuery;

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnString))
{
    using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand())
    {
        int i;
        comm.Connection = conn;
        conn.Open();
        StrQuery = "INSERT INTO communTable VALUES (@code1,@model1,@name1,@type1,@price1)";
        for (i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                comm.Parameters.Add("@code1", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value;
                comm.Parameters.Add("@model1", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value;
                comm.Parameters.Add("@name1", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value;
                comm.Parameters.Add("@type1", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value;
                comm.Parameters.Add("@price1", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value;
                comm.CommandText = StrQuery;
                comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                comm.Parameters.Clear();
            }
        conn.Close();
        if (i == dataGridView1.Rows.Count)
            MessageBox.Show("SUCCES!");
        else
            MessageBox.Show("FAILED!");
    }
}
```

The message box shows success so I'm sure the loop works fine, also when I execute this again an error shows up telling me I have duplicates so I'm positive it's saving, but when I close the form and check the database on Visual Studio I find it empty.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you make sure you're checking the database that it's actually performing the insert on? My guess is you have more copies of the database than you realize. By the way, there's no need to compare the index variable (i) with the number of rows in the DataGridView. If it makes it that far without an exception, you can be assured it was successful.

Comment: Don't use attached databases like this. Why? Aaron Bertrand explains this quite clearly [here](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-attachdbfilename/). Seems very likely this is your problem.

Comment: @SeanLange THANK YOU SO MUCH! this was bothering me the whole afternoon and I was trying to fix the wrong problem.

Comment: @mason I already did the copies mistake lol that wasn't it, also thanks for the remark about comparing i, I'm fairly new to both C# and SQL and I got a little bit skeptical about that one, thanks for your quick reply.

Comment: Cool glad you figured out a solution.

Comment: @Flydog57 Looks like they're following the pattern pretty closely already, except for the superfluous closing of the connection. Is there a specific reason you think they need to read up on it more?